# Android listView onScroll stuttering animation when scrolling down

Tags: android, listview, scroll

So right now when I scroll down it hides the toolbar and the floating bottom, until I hit the edge of the top of the next view item. All of the hidden stuff appears for a milisecond and then goes back to hiding, even while im only scrolling down.

Any advice?

```
mListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        private int mLastFirstVisibleItem;

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                             int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            Animation fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade_in);
            Animation fadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade_out);

        if(mLastFirstVisibleItem != firstVisibleItem) {
            if (mLastFirstVisibleItem < firstVisibleItem) {

                bottomBar.startAnimation(fadeOut);
                bottomBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                fab.startAnimation(fadeOut);
                fab.hide(true);

            }
            else {
                bottomBar.startAnimation(fadeIn);
                bottomBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                fab.startAnimation(fadeIn);
                fab.show(true);

            }
        }
            mLastFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;

        }
    });
```

Comment: Make the fadeIn and fadeOut animations class accessible and load them when the class is being initialized. Loading them every time the scroll is happening is very expensive and is definitely slowing things down significantly

Answer (score 0):

Hey try something like this:

```
final Animation fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade_in);
final Animation fadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade_out);
        listViewRight.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

                if(mLastFirstVisibleItem != firstVisibleItem) {
                    if (mLastFirstVisibleItem < firstVisibleItem && (bottomBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)) {

                        fadeOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                                bottomBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                fab.hide(true);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                            }
                        });

                        bottomBar.startAnimation(fadeOut);
                        fab.startAnimation(fadeOut);

                    }
                    else if ((bottomBar.getVisibility() == View.GONE)) {

                        fadeIn.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                                bottomBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                fab.show(true);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {


                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                            }
                        });
                        bottomBar.startAnimation(fadeIn);
                        fab.startAnimation(fadeIn);


                    }
                }
                mLastFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;



            }
        });
```

Even though i still don't understand what you are trying to achieve as the logic of that animation is a bit weird, but still should definitly smooth things up a bit!

**Edit: Update the code**

Comment: This seems like it sped up my ListView but it still makes the floating button and the toolbar appear while scrolling down. It flashes for a millisecond and then fades again after passing through each item.

Comment: of course because your algorithm is wrong!(no ofense) what are you trying to achieve by the way?

Comment: Sorry, I got the algorithm from stack. What i'm trying to achieve is just that on scroll down the floating button and toolbar fade out, and on scroll up they fade in

Comment: yeah i guess you need to check first if the view is already gone first so you dont re animate it ...i have update the code (Ps it is just an example you can domuch better than that :) )